# Retornar imagem por Web Service REST Server

Tags: delphi, web-service, rest, datasnap

Tenho um `Web Service REST` rodando, esse web service faz a consulta no `ERP` quando o cliente solicita a requisição de um determinado dado, precisava retornar a imagem que o cliente fez a requisição e mostrar no browser.

fiz o seguinte código que retorna um stream, mas mesmo assim não tive sucesso.

> Result := TFileStream.Create(sDirImagem,fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);

Comment: Olha, não sei te dizer se é esse o seu problema, mas eu já tive problemas em trafegar imagens entre serviços. Ele simplesmente só aceitava tipos nativos A solução foi converter a imagem para base64 e trafega-lo como string.

Comment: Consegui resolver, mas preciso converter a imagem para base64 mesmo, estou testando com o Postman, para ver se ele mostra a imagem convertida em base64. Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar a imagem direito no navegador, consegui resolver do seguinte modo, usei a função `GetInvocationMetaData`, tenho que especificar para o navegador qual o retorno. Vou colocar um exemplo de como eu fiz:

declarar no usues `Data.DBXPlatform`

```
function CarregarImagem(const sCaminho: String): AnsiString;
var
  oFileStream : TFileStream;
begin
  oFileStream:= TFileStream.Create(sCaminho, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
 if oFileStream.Size > 0 then
 begin
   SetLength(Result, oFileStream.Size);
   oFileStream.Read(Pointer(Result)^, oFileStream.Size);
 end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(oFileStream);      
end;
```

end;

```
sImagem := CarregarImagem(sDirImagem);       
if (bExtPNG) then
  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContentType := 'image/png'
else
begin
  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseCode := 200;
  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := sImagem;
  GetInvocationMetadata().CloseSession    := True;
end;
```