# Como retornar a imagem convertida em base64 no Postman

Tags: delphi, web-service, rest, datasnap

Tenho um `Web Service REST Server`, preciso trafegar uma imagem do web service para o cliente, quando o cliente faz a requisição de uma determinada imagem, o web service faz a conversão para `base64` e manda para o cliente.

Queria saber como que eu faço para testar o retorno dessa imagem no `Postman`.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Qual é o sentido da pergunta? Você perguntou "Alguém usa o Postman para testes?". Se você quer opiniões sobre o Postman, aqui não é o lugar ideal para isso. Senão seja mais específico.

Comment: Se você visualizar as tag e o título, já deve perceber o sentido da pergunta, expliquei o que eu fiz e depois perguntei se alguém já testou o retorno da imagem convertida de base64 no Postman, você já testou?... ou só veio criticar minha pergunta. Abraços.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retornar imagem por Web Service REST Server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158608/retornar-imagem-por-web-service-rest-server)

Comment: Não meu caro, só quis ajudar você a melhorar sua pergunta e ao mesmo tempo ajudar o fórum. Consulte esse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) sobre o que não perguntar.

Comment: Arrumei a pergunta, espero ter sido específico, desculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Bom, até onde eu sei, o Postman só apresenta pretty format para XML e JSON. Para visualizar creio que você terá que usar um app externo. O que você pode fazer é passar um parâmetro para a requisição quando quiser testar de forma que o retorno seja a base64 dentro de uma tag `img`: `<img src=”data:<MIMETYPE>;base64,<código>”>`. Dessa forma você pode ver a imagem no preview que os navegadores apresentam na aba network. Lembrando que o Postam também tem um preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só com o código puro base64 acredito que você não conseguirá.

O que você pode fazer é passar um parâmetro na requisição, quando quiser testar, indicando que você quer colocar o código base64 dentro de uma tag `img`. E ter um retorno como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw......" />
```

Dessa forma é possível visualizar no Postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estive dando uma olhada na documentação do postman, tem que  especificar no ContenType = 'image/png', que seria o retorno. Mas tenho que montar a tag para visualizar a imagem então. valeu pela ajuda Felix.